# How to open a firebird .db table file using c#.Net

Tags: c#, .net, database, firebird

I have a Firebird .fdb file and can open it fine.
But some tables are empty, and I can open the .db files of these tables using 3rd part programs. This was not developed by me.

Now I need to open a .db from a table from firebird using c#.net
Some knows how to do that?
I dont want to open the database, connect to it, etc, just open the .db file.

Comment: what do you mean by opening db file without opening the database and connecting?

Comment: @Giorgi I guess Bruno wants to read the database file from the file system instead of connecting to the DB and retrieving the data. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, i need to open the .db file. Its a really bad system that i need to work with, to synchronize some data. It has a DB folder with the .fbd files that I can open, and some .db files alone, with data. I can open the .db files using programs like Database desktop, but i need to use some code to read it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can open those .db files using Borland Database Desktop, then they are Paradox tables and not Firebird ones.

So, in order to access that .db files from your C# app, you could use:

- MS ODBC Paradox Driver
- MS Jet OLEDB

Keep in mind that you may have to install/configure BDE (Borland Database Engine), so the MS drivers would provide full support on Paradox tables.

Comment: Thanks, its a system that uses both Firebird and Paradox, i didn't know that because the Paradox tables (.db files) are the same as the Firebird tables.
I could open the Paradox tables using MS Jet OLEDB and getting the Borland BDE. Wouldn't open without the BDE running.